# Progress bar with 2 Indicators

Tags: android, progress-bar, greenfoot

I want to have progress bar with 2 indicators.

One indicator shows progress of task A in color green, the second indicator shows progress of task B in red, all in one progress bar. The rest shows the remaining of tasks A and B.

Is there a (simple) solution to achieve this? I read the documentation but did not find help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done by coding the two indicators as the Primary progress and secondary progress of the same progress bar.

create a sub class for the progress bar.

```
public class TextProgressBar extends ProgressBar {
    private Paint textPaint;

    public TextProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public TextProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        setMax(30);
        setProgress(12);
        setSecondaryProgress(20);

    }

}
```

The XML entry for the progress bar has to be referred to using this sub class.

```
<com.darsh.doubleProgressBar.TextProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="15sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress" />
```

now create the drawable in the resources directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#ff747674"
            android:startColor="#ff5a5d5a" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />


            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#32cd32"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#32cd32"
                android:startColor="#32cd32" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#33B5E5"
                android:startColor="#33B5E5" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

The colors for the primary and secondary indicators can be changed in this drawable.

Make use of them in your code like this:

```
TextProgressBar textProgress;
textProgress = (TextProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
textProgress.setMax(100);
textProgress.setProgress(10); //
textProgress.setSecondaryProgress(50); //green
```

Comment: 2 quick questions: `android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"`, should that be `android:id="@+id/secondaryProgress"`? And why create a subclass? You create a private field, but don't use it.

Comment: Disregard the first question, I got it: You need to set the id from the Android set, so as to let the ProgressBar know which shape to use.

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom layuout and put the two progressbars in it. Then you need to manipulate the progressbars by getting their handle. If its for a notification, you  have to set it as a  remote View.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean