# customizing progress bar in custom notification

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-notifications, android-progressbar

I'm trying to implement a notification with two progress bars in it. I referred customizing the progress bar of the notification from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10390258/1455531). I keep getting this error & m not able to figure out a solution. plz help.

```
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525): couldn't inflate view for notification mobishare.notify/0x50ae95c1
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class mobishare.notify.customProgressBar
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:1303)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.makeNotificationView(StatusBarService.java:597)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.addNotificationViews(StatusBarService.java:634)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.addNotification(StatusBarService.java:431)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.CommandQueue$H.handleMessage(CommandQueue.java:201)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mobishare.notify.customProgressBar in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[.]
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
    07-16 13:26:30.523: E/StatusBarService(1525):   ... 17 more
```

**EDIT:**
Or if any body could tell me how to add 2 progress bars in notification. Any help appreciated.

Comment: do you got solution??? I am facing same problem with progresswheel library please help if you got it thanks...

Comment: nopes. Please post it if you find any.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path of the custom progress bar is written correctly in the XML file.. as the problem is the system cannot find the class.. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mobishare.notify.customProgressBar`

Comment: the path is correct. It seems that there is something else that needs to be done.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781151/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-on-working-app may be it helps