# Android ProgressBar animation

Tags: android, user-interface

This seems like it should be a simple question, but for some reason I haven't come up with an obvious answer yet:

I have a horizontal progress bar displayed by my app while it does some work in the background.  There are a finite amount of steps in this process, so I display actual progress rather than using an indeterminate progress bar.

However, there are occasionally steps in this process that take a very long time, so the progress bar is stationary for a while.

I could update the progress at a finer resolution, but I'd rather have the progress bar "pulse" or show some other constant animation just so that the user can see it is still working.  I assumed Android would have this built in without me having to do much work, since it's such a common UI feature, but I can only seem to get this to work if I use an indeterminate progress bar.

Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to write some kind of custom animation?

Comment: Have you tried using Android spinning circle for each step in addition to entire process progress bar? This way the user knows that process is still active.

Comment: I suppose I should have specified in the question:  I need to avoid covering up the screen while this is going on.  It's ok for me to have a small progress bar at the bottom like I do currently, but unfortunately having a spinning circle or anything else of substantial size would interfere with some things the app needs to do.  Hope that isn't too vague!

Comment: In that case, you can customize the progress bar to have two indicators [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387435/progress-bar-with-2-indicators)

Comment: That would definitely accomplish my goal, thanks!